# What should the appropriate model for my data look like?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

My research objective is that I would like to test if some sounds in languages are similar to each other in terms of duration.

In my situation, I have 4 languages with 5 sounds. The first three languages have all 5 sounds but only one language has 3 sounds. My items are divided into 6 vowels and all languages have all these 6 vowels.

Then I have speakers of 4 languages but 2 languages are produced by the same group of speakers - so actually I have 3 groups of speakers instead of 4 (each group has both males and females).

As duration is continuous variable, I am using Linear mixed model (LMM) in R with lme4. My fixed effects are language + vowel + sex + sound. My random effects are speaker + item.

However, I am not sure what the proper model should look like in my case. I have tried this formula: 
`lmer4 <- lmer(Duration ~ (1|item) + (1+sound*vowel|speaker) + vowel*sex*sound*Language, data=data.frame,REML=FALSE)`

but the model cannot be run because some sounds do not exist in some languages. Does anyone have any idea about the appropriate model for my case? Your help would be exactly grateful.

Comment: +1 for beginning your question with a statement of your research objective. Questions on this site can often benefit from an opening statement such as this, putting into context the statistical detail that follows.